# Google Maps view in Java application

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

My goal is to have a GPS Track displayed in a local Java Application with Google Maps. And I am pretty sure I am not the first one to try this, so there should be a way.

The Problem is that I found the [Google Maps Engine API (Deprecated)](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/) which is stated as deprecated. But I didn't find any replacement. Only [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/mapsengine/v1#add-library-to-your-project) page, which then links to the deprecated version again. 
I also did some search, but all results seem to point to future deprecated API, and also are pretty old.
Can anyone point me a version or tooling that I will be able to still use in 2016? Or does anyone know an alternative to using Google Maps for displaying GPS tracks in a local java app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem:
I used mapsforge https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge

Answer (score 0):

[JxMaps](https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps) library provides possibility to add Google Maps to java swing application. Using this library you can draw GPS track either as polyline or set of markers on the map.